# Update in codeigniter using rest api

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to upload a photo in codeigniter using rest api

Comment: this path is wrong `$uploaddir = '/home/me/public_html/uploads/'; `

Comment: i edited my question now do you have any idea of how to upload image using codeigniter rest api

Comment: Nothing to do with rest. Check this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: But i want to do it with rest api

Comment: I am trying to upload image using rest api in codeigniter, and I edited it again, now do you guys have any idea of how to do it,                                it says the error of undefined index:file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the documentation given in codeigniter,
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

it is not related to rest API, code for all are same for file uploading, you have to make **"multipart/form-data"** content type request to upload the file.